# 2mA Current Limiter from a dc to dc converter

Tags: current, converter

I have a 12V power supply connected in a 12V to 5V dc to dc converter. The problem is, the current at the 5V side is 5A which my optocouplers cannot handle in fact, the only current i need is 2mA.The reason i used a dc to dc converter is to power a lower voltage circuit and the galvanic isolation is important. Is there a way to limit the current to 2mA or slightly higher? Thank you

Comment: I doubt if you understand what you're doing. A 5V, 5A DCDC converter will only deliver 5 A **when the load allows that current to flow**. 2mA looks like a current through a LED (include a schematic of that !!!) simply add a series resistor to make that 2 mA flow. If that is problematic for you I advise a basic course in electronics. There are plenty books and websites to teach you the basics.

Comment: Almost all power supplies (except ones designed specifically for LEDs) are constant voltage supplies. Constant voltage supplies provide a constant voltage regardless of what current you need. I mean, a 5V 5A supply will always put out 5V but will only supply the current that the load requires. This is the same reason why you can plug a 60W desk lamp into a 2400W outlet and *not* have it explode. The voltage is fixed but the current is only what the load needs.

Answer (score 0):

A series resistor will do the trick.  You have 5V coming out of the DC-DC converter.  The maximum current the DC-DC converter can deliver is 5A.  If you need 2mA, use Ohm's Law to calculate the resistor value you will need.

$$V=RI$$

$$5/0.002 = 2500   Ohms$$

Depending on the operating current of the optocoupler, I would choose a resistor in that range to achieve that galvanic isolation.

Comment: [*ohms*, not *Ohms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm)